# Brute force on Hydra with non-ASCII usernames and passwords

Tags: hydra

I use Hydra with the Web-Form (Http-Post-Form); and I'm trying to use a list of Usernames when some of the nicks contain a letter ñ.
For example I have the following account in my list:

```
Username: ñandu123
Password: asd123
```

The script that I run is something like this:

```
hydra -L usernames.txt -P passwords.txt www.xxxxx.com http-post-form "/login.php:log_user=^USER^&log_pass=^PASS^&Enter.x=0&Enter.y=0:ERROR."
```

Inside the usernames.txt and passwords.txt (encoded as ANSI) is already the account of "**ñandu123**" but the script never detects it. It works well with usernames without an special char but not when I use this letter "ñ".

I don't know how I can make the script to detect these special chars inside my list files.

If I use the word "ñandu123" directly the script works well (`-l ñandu`)

```
hydra -l ñandu123 -P passwords.txt www.xxxxx.com http-post-form "/login.php:log_user=^USER^&log_pass=^PASS^&Enter.x=0&Enter.y=0:ERROR."
```

But not when I use the username list.
And I cannot do this "one by one" because I have more than 200 usernames, so I need the list.

Comment: Did you try to run them with `LANG=C` environment:  `LANG=C LANGUAGE=C hydra -L usernames.txt... `

Answer (score 2):

This seem linked to language environment:

You could try:

```
LANG=C LANGUAGE=C hydra -L usernames.txt -P passwords.txt \
  www.xxxxx.com http-post-form \
  "/login.php:log_user=^USER^&log_pass=^PASS^&Enter.x=0&Enter.y=0:ERROR."
```

or

```
recode lat1..u8 <usernames.txt >usernames.u8
```

or if `usernames.txt` is already *`UTF-8`*:

```
recode u8..lat1 <usernames.txt >usernames.lat1
```

Then again.

```
LANG=C LANGUAGE=C hydra -L usernames.u8 ...
```

Comment: This method worked.